# 2nd Hard Drive appearing as BD Drive in Windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I just installed a 2nd hard drive, in a caddy, in my Lenovo Y510p. When I boot back into Windows 8.1, Windows recognizes it as a DVD Drive.

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you open the disk does it contain the contents of the drive?

Comment: @Ramhound No, it is treating it as a disc drive and "tries" to eject it.

Comment: There are numerous articles on this behavior.  What have you tried to fix it to eliminate possible fixes?

Comment: @Ramhound I have went into Disk Management and basically tried every option. I know other programs recognize it, for example Clonezilla knows I have an SSD in there however my computer still thinks it is the DVD drive, which i took out.